# Diagonal Movement

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

In 4e did they remove the 1 and 1/2 movement rules for moveing diagonaly so that I can say move (with a speed of 5) 5 squares in any direction making a 11x11, or 121, boxs of potential movement options or is it still like the 3.5 rules were a move of 5 or 25ft would give you a circle like shape with a diameter of 11 squares or 55ft provideing 89 movement options.

Comment: Please join chat if you're interested in discussing this further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, 4E removed the approximations in 3E and 3.5E for all forms of measuring distance. In 4E you just count grid squares.

This simplifies movement and distance calculations, and effectively turns all circles into squares in terms of area of effect, range of attacks (and reach) etc.

Comment: I may have to house rule to the old system then. I have alwase liked how D&D made movement feal more natural unlike the commonly seen diamonds and squares.

Comment: @user9142 That way lies madness! Honesty, all of 4Es mechanics and systems are built around the square grid. You can most likely will unhinge a lot of things that work fine as is.

Comment: @user9142 everything is counted in squares, there isn't really an difference for 4e in moving 5 squares back and 5 square diagonally.

Comment: @Zim20000: I originally had the same reaction when changing systems, but I never saw it through to an actual house-rule. For a fun 4E battle, it's far more important IMO to put some interesting terrain on the map than to model the distances accurately.

Answer (score 8):

**Correct**

4e's movement rules are all in squares (representing 5 feet, but no power or feat will ever mention real distance, only distance in squares) and powers, feats, and class features all use number of squares to denote range, and area size of attacks. Rather than being a circle (like in real life/a more simulationist game) 4e's burst and blast attack powers hit an area of the map that is a square.

**Distance moved diagonal is exactly the same as distance moved in a straight line.**
Its important that diagonal movement is equal to straight line movement because close burst, burst, and blast powers all hit squares in the grid in a X by X square pattern. Thus moving diagonal does not inherently give the PCs or monsters an advantage in escaping any kind of of attack (be it ranged, burst, close burst, or blast)

*Close burst* powers emanate out from the player's square by 1 concentric square for each size noted. Here's an example of a close burst 1 power: (0 = not targeted, x = player, + = targeted square)

```
ooooo  
o+++o  
o+x+o  
o+++o  
ooooo
```

Blast powers emanate from the player square in one direction and one square of the blast must meet the edge of the player's square. Thus for a blast 3 power: (0 = not targeted, x = player, + = hit square)

```
00000000  
0000+++0  
0000+++0  
000x+++0  
00000000  
00000000
```

Lastly, *Burst* powers hit a target space and emanate outward. Thus for a burst 1 power: (0 = not targeted, x = player, + = hit square, z = target square)

```
0000+++0  
0000+Z+0  
0000+++0  
000x0000  
00000000  
00000000
```

FYI, if you want better visuals and need any other rules for 4e clarified I would look at this [Quick Start Guide](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/quickstartrules.pdf).

Comment: I had trouble with Blast vs. Burst for a long time, trying to figure out which used radius and which used diameter (~ish; we're talking squares, not circles here!) I finally came up with the mnemonic that Burst contains an R, and uses Radius. Blast does not.